# React preview images after inserting input type files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On a page to modify a product I fetch to fill in the fields and display the images that's ok. But when I want to change the images by an input type files the images no longer display. My imgCollection variable is updated, but not the render. How do I update my render every time my variable changes? thanks

```
...
this.state = {  imgCollection: '' }
this.handleChangeImgCollection = this.handleChangeImgCollection.bind(this)

    handleChangeImgCollection = event => {
        this.setState({ imgCollection: event.target.files })
    }

render() {
  const {imgCollection} = this.state
  const imgDisplay = []

       for (let i = 0; i < imgCollection.length; i++) {
            imgDisplay.push(<img src={imgCollection[i]} key={[i]} alt="img" />);
        }
  return (
    { imgDisplay }

     <Form.Group>
      <Form.File defaultValue={imgCollection}
         className="position-relative"
           id="custom-file"
           label="Inserer des images"
           type="file"
           name="imgCollection"
           onChange={this.handleChangeImgCollection} 
           multiple
           required
          />
       </Form.Group>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution I do not know if it is the best one chose to do in react but it works .. Complicated image management

````
...
this.state = {  imgCollection: '' }   // urls fetch
this.handleChangeImgCollection = this.handleChangeImgCollection.bind(this)

  handleChangeImgCollection = event => {
     var preview = document.querySelector('#preview')
     var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
     var displayimgC = document.querySelector('.displayImgCollection')
        
     preview.innerHTML = '<div id="preview"></div>'
     displayimgC.style.visibility = 'hidden'
     displayimgC.style.height = "0px"

   const readAndPreview = (file) => {
     if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
          var image = new Image();
          image.height = 200;
          image.title = file.name;
          image.src = this.result;
          preview.appendChild(image);
        }, false);
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
    if (files) {
      [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
    }
    this.setState({ imgCollection: event.target.files })
 }

render() {
  const {imgCollection} = this.state
  const imgDisplay = []

  for (let i = 0; i < imgCollection.length; i++) {
      imgDisplay.push(imgCollection[i]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     <div className="justify-content-md-center p-3">
        <div id="preview"></div>
        <div className="displayImgCollection">{imgDisplay}</div>

     <Form.Group>
      <Form.File defaultValue={imgCollection}
         className="position-relative"
           id="custom-file"
           label="Inserer des images"
           type="file"
           name="imgCollection"
           onChange={this.handleChangeImgCollection} 
           multiple
           required
          />
       </Form.Group>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
render() {
  const {imgCollection} = this.state
  const imgDisplay = []

  for (let i = 0; i < imgCollection.length; i++) {
      imgDisplay.push(imgCollection[i]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
     {imgDisplay.map((image,indx) => <img src={image} key={indx} alt=`img_${indx}` />}

     <Form.Group>
      <Form.File defaultValue={imgCollection}
         className="position-relative"
           id="custom-file"
           label="Inserer des images"
           type="file"
           name="imgCollection"
           onChange={this.handleChangeImgCollection} 
           multiple
           required
          />
       </Form.Group>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: um i didn't understand this is supposed to update the render when the this.state.imgCollection changes?
When I load the page the images are well rendered however when I insert the new images it is not displayed

Comment: In fact when new images are loaded I receive a "$$ typeof: Symbol (react.element)" and do not know how to display that

Comment: other thing set name ``name="imgCollection[]"``